# How to get place name with CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

For example: i'm standing at shop. I'm starting use my app and it should return shop name. Does `CoreLocation` library do this or i should use google library ?

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreLocation offers a geocoder service ([CLGeocoder, Apple documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html) that allows for translation back and forth between lat/lon coordinates and street addresses. However, this service does not provide business/resident names, so you will have to use a third-party service to get that information.